# Função de verificação só retorna vazia

Tags: php

Fiz essas duas funções bem simples pra limitar os caracteres e pra ver se a coluna no banco ta vazia, por algum motivo só retorna vazia mesmo tendo resultados.

```
public function limite_texto($texto, $limite, $complemento) {
    return mb_strimwidth(utf8_encode($texto), 0, $limite, $complemento);
}

public function vazio($texto, $limite, $complemento, $aviso) {
    if (empty($texto)) :
        return $aviso;
    else :
        return $this->limite_texto($texto, $limite, $complemento);
    endif;
}

$ctlr->vazio("oooooi", 3, "...", "O campo está vazio")
```

Por algum motivo ta retornando apenas os "...", quando o esperado seria "ooo..." ou se a variavel `$texto` fosse vazia retornasse `O campo está vazio`, acho que errei na logica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você definiu que a função deve retornar 3 caracteres, você obteve 3 caracteres, mas achou estranho porque não vieram 6? Estranho.

Talvez faltou mais atenção ao ler a documentação das funções que está utilizando:

> [`mb_strimwidth`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strimwidth.php)
>
> Valor retornado: *The truncated string. If `trimmarker` is set, `trimmarker` replaces the last chars to match the width.*

É retornada a *string* truncada, mas se o valor de `trimmarker` for definido, `trimmarker` irá substituir os últimos caracteres da *string* até atingir o tamanho limite.

Ou seja, você passa a *string* `"oooooi"`, que truncada seria `"ooo"`, mas como definiu o valor de `trimmarker`, ele substituirá os últimos caracteres até ter no máximo 3 caracteres (limite que você definiu).

Portanto, a saída sempre será `"..."`, pois apenas o valor de `trimmarker` já atinge o limite de caracteres que você definiu.

Se o objetivo era obter `"ooo..."`, você deveria ter definido o limite como 6, visto que você quer ter 6 caracteres na saída.

Comment: A intenção era fazer essa função adicionar os "3 pontinhos" limitando a número de caracteres somente da variavel `$texto`